# How to run PostgreSQL "CREATE SEQUENCE" syntax in (memory-based) HSQLDB?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm running a PostgreSQL database migrated via Flyway. The initial script contains this sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1000
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;
```

The migration runs fine.

Now I want to run some tests against my system, using an in-memory HSQLDB as the test setup. I connect to this HSQLDB using Postgres syntax already:

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb;sql.syntax_pgs=true");
```

But I still get this error while the migration script runs:

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: CACHE : line: 6

I suspect that this setup isn't possible, as [the HSQLDB documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#create_sequence-section) doesn't mention a `CACHE` option ([as PostgreSQL does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html)). Is this true? Is there any workaround, maybe in using some other syntax or something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just remove the `cache` part.

Comment: Cannot do so, as this would invalidate the migration script. Besides it wouldn't solve the problem of how to run valid PostgreSQL...

Comment: The only DBMS that can run a valid Postgres query is Postgres. And a migration from one DBMS to another means you need to remove features that are not offered by the "new" DBMS from your queries. So the only choice you have is to remove the CACHE from the statement or enhance HSQLDB to support a cache parameter

Comment: Thanks for clarification